# How to register Polymer behavior with ES6?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

If I do

```
Polymer({
    is: 'pp-app',
    behaviors: [PlayPlan.HelperBehavior],
    scrollPageToTop() {
      document.getElementById('mainContainer').scrollTop = 0;
    },

    onDataRouteClick() {
      var drawerPanel = document.querySelector('#paperDrawerPanel');
      if (drawerPanel.narrow) {
        drawerPanel.closeDrawer();
      }
    }
  });
```

The behavior here will works fine, but in es6

```
  class PlayPlanApp {
    beforeRegister() {
      this.is = 'pp-app';
      this.properties = {};
      this.behaviors = [PlayPlan.HelperBehavior];
    }

    scrollPageToTop() {
      document.getElementById('mainContainer').scrollTop = 0;
    }

    onDataRouteClick() {
      var drawerPanel = document.querySelector('#paperDrawerPanel');
      if (drawerPanel.narrow) {
        drawerPanel.closeDrawer();
      }
    }
  }
  Polymer(PlayPlanApp);
```

The behavior will not works, how to specify behaviors when using es6 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by

```
registerCallback: function() {
      // TODO(sjmiles): perhaps this method should be called from polymer-bootstrap?
      this._desugarBehaviors(); // abstract
      this._doBehavior('beforeRegister'); // abstract
      this._registerFeatures();  // abstract
      this._doBehavior('registered'); // abstract
    }
```

`_doBehavior('beforeRegister')` is after `_desugarBehaviors`, here is an work around:

```
get behaviors() {
      return [PlayPlan.HelperBehavior];
    }
```

BTW, this will not work, because the constructor never get called(commented in Polymer.Base)

```
constructor() {
      return [PlayPlan.HelperBehavior];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the answer given by wener will not work if you use extended behaviors. Extended behaviors in Polymer are arrays of behaviors themselves. I don't know what's going on exactly but apparently Polymer is parsing the protoype of your class and flattening the behavior array, writing the flattened version back to your prototype. The fixed getter function will ignore the flattened version and always return the deep array. That will not do. So you have two options.
You can flatten the array yourself:

```
get behaviors() {
    return [
        MyFlatBehavior, MyExtendedBehavior
    ].reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b);});
}
```

However, since Polymer may call get behaviors a lot (it does in my case), this will introduce a minor performance penalty. The alternative is letting it set the behaviors:

```
let SkeletonPolymerBehavior = [MyFlatBehavior, MyExtendedBehavior];
class SkeletonPolymer {
    get behaviors( ) {return SkeletonPolymerBehavior;}
    set behaviors(b) {SkeletonPolymerBehavior = b;}
    ...
}
```

Finally you can flatten the array right away:

```
let SkeletonPolymerBehavior = [
    MyFlatBehavior, MyExtendedBehavior
].reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b);});
class SkeletonPolymer {
    get behaviors( ) {return SkeletonPolymerBehavior;}
    ...
}
```

Note that my flatten function is *not* safe! It worked in my case, but it will fail when extending extended behaviors and possibly in other cases. You definitely need something more sophisticated there. If you don't want to bother (and I see no compelling reason to) you should definitely go with the second version, letting Polymer set the behaviors.

Final note: I tried abstracting that away into an es2015 Behaviors mixin. However, Polymer's prototype magic does not catch stuff inherited from base classes and the getters and setters defined there are never called.

However, it is possible to mess with the prototype the es5 way. This utility function will ease the addition of extended behaviors:

```
function addBehaviors(clas, ...behaviors) {
    let bhv = behaviors;
    Object.defineProperty(clas.prototype, "behaviors", {
        get:function( ) {return bhv;},
        set:function(b) {return bhv = b;}
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
class SkeletonPolymer {...}
addBehaviors(SkeletonPolymer, MyFlatBehavior, MyExtendedBehavior);
```